# How do I open android application from address bar?

Tags: android

I want to copy and paste an url to address bar and it will open my android application

I have set up a deep-link for my android application and it works well when I click it on browser. However, it doesn't work when I copy and paste that to address bar. Is that the logic of android or I have missed something. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

```
<activity
        android:name="com.webviewtestapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/deep-link"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: You have missed a couple of thing. What you need is deeplink. Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking or here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deep-linking-in-android-with-example/

Comment: I am not aware of any Web browser that supports what you are seeking.